# Passing Javascript variable to php on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to pass a javascript variable to php on the same page. I tried some code but nothing worked.

The current code looks like this:

```
function init(e){
 $('#DeleteDaily').click(function() {
  d = document.getElementById("DailyRequestsList");
  selected = d.selectedIndex;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "index.php?i=" + selected, true);
  xhttp.send();
 });
}
$(document).ready(init);
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['DeleteDaily'])) {
    $Index = $_GET['i'];
    }
  ?>
 });
});
```

If I try to use Index as an argument for a python script it should delete an entry in a textfile and an element from a select object should be deleted on the website which doesn't happen. The python script itself works fine.
But I don't know why the variable isn't passed to php.

Comment: You'll never have both a `$_GET` and `$_POST` property in a given request, so your if statement will never run.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just "mix" javascript and PHP like you're doing.

If that is inside a web page, the PHP code will be rendered (in your case, it will return nothing), and the page will just interpret an *empty* javascript function.

You need that PHP to be on the server, or turn it into javascript...

Comment: The problem is that I need to get the Index of the select object which you can't do with php. After that I have to use php to call a python script on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

you can done it by

PHP Code

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['DeleteDaily'])) {
    $Index = $_GET['i'];
  }else{
     $Index='';
  }
?>
```

Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
       var index = '<?php echo $Index;?>';
       if(index  == ''){
         //put your code
       }else{
         //put your code
       }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is the wrong way. This is the way to pass php to javascript. I'm trying to pass javascript to php.